# How to log user out if disabled or deleted? (Firebase auth)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am listening to AUTH changes:

```
  async onAuthStateChanged() {
    await firebase.auth().currentUser.reload();
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user_auth) => {
        if (user_auth) {
            //user signed in
        } else {
            ///log out
            unsubscribe();
            this.props.navigation.navigate('login');
        }
    })
}
```

I call `onAuthStateChanged()` from `onComponentDidMount()` however it doesnt trigger it when I delete/disable a user from Firebase Console.

Comment: The user's token is good for 1 hour even if the user is deleted in the console.  The listener will not be updated in real time.

Comment: @DougStevenson that sucks big time. How am I suppose to just log a user out which I deleted ?!

Comment: Wait one hour. Or arrange to send the app a push message saying that the user was deleted and should be forced to log out using the auth api.